# Snap keeps old versions of programs updates

Tags: snap

When Snap updates a program it keeps the before versions installed. For example, I had Skype installed with the 60 version ( 567 MB ),but then it was updated with 63 version (606 MB) and finally the actual 66 version ( 607 MB ). As is the program uses 1.7 GB in the hard disc. If an user has in his system a few programs installed using Snap, probably it doesn't a big problem but if the idea is that in the future the most program is istalling as is, it will use a lot of space in the hard disc, and the process won't be efficient. If I uninstall Skype and re install again, it uses only 607 MB. If this issue is not known, how can I comunicate to Ubuntu programers to review it and try to improve the process ?

Comment: You can avoid Snaps by installing software from APT from official and third-party repositories/PPAs. For example Skype has [deb-package version](https://go.skype.com/skypeforlinux-64.deb).

Answer (score 4):

The [developers were already discussing it](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/configure-number-of-old-revisions-to-keep/2337) long ago...and did something about it.

Your Ubuntu system, using snapd, will keep the current snap, plus two older snaps, for a total of three. Three is the default. You can reduce this to two using:

```
snap set system refresh.retain=N
```

N cannot be less than 2.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I read the other answer before this with this command: snap remove --revision=<an old one> snapname, and it was useful. I didn't use your command but probably is useful too. I use the other command and made the job well.