# How to run a previous version of a snap package

Tags: snap

I have a snap package installed and I would like to run a previous version of it temporarily to test something.

I can see several versions of this package is installed in `/var/lib/snapd/snaps/`

Is there a simple (possibly one liner) command to run the previous version?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

- List installed versions in your system:

  ```bsh
  $ snap list intellij-idea-ultimate  --all

  Name                    Version   Rev  Tracking       Publisher   Notes
  intellij-idea-ultimate  2019.3.4  212  latest/stable  jetbrains✓  disabled,classic
  intellij-idea-ultimate  2020.1    216  latest/stable  jetbrains✓  classic
  ```
- Revert to a previous one:

  ```
  sudo snap revert intellij-idea-ultimate
  ```
- Revert to a specific revision:

  ```
  sudo snap revert intellij-idea-ultimate --revision 212
  ```

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D_tXAWGsys8&ab_channel=Lazo00100001

Comment: Thanks a lot, very good explanation.

Comment: Does reverting also disable auto-update for that snap?  Or does it only skip the current version until the next update?

Comment: It skips the version only until the next system update.

I reverted a snap to a previous version and after some time a sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade automatically installed the latest available version. I was keeping an eye out but didn't even noticed it.

Comment: Does the snap-system actually keep older versions? Or is it package-dependent? I did a list today for `Inkscape`, it did show an older version, but it was marked `disabled` like your example shows, and wouldn't revert. Next time I listed it, only the latest version showed up, not the older one. Sigh... Arg. just re-read that, you're talking about *local* stored versions. Is there a way to see what's remote?

Comment: _1. Does the snap-system actually keep older versions?_
- Yes. More info: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1105878/snap-keeps-old-versions-of-programs-updates

_2. Is there a way to see what's remote?_
- Not from command line (at the time of writing). Use `snap info <program_name>` then go to the url which is found in the `contact` section. Go to "Overview" (top left), then click "View full publishing history" (top right).

Example: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+publishinghistory

Comment: **Un-revert** is rather unintuitive: `sudo snap refresh someapp`