# How to rename snap application file in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, snap, android-studio

This morning I got Android Studio updated, and now it has a bug. The solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68572505/after-updating-to-android-studio-arctic-fox-i-cannot-use-any-custom-theme/68599712#68599712), so I just need to rename snap's file, how can I do this, if snap files are read-only?

Maybe there is a way to downgrade to the previous version of Android Studio? Because now when I do `snap info android-studio` it seems like there are no channels with previous versions.

Comment: Did you report the bug to the Snap author? The Snap ecosystem is designed so that bugfixes can be pushed out rapidly. Up to four times each day

Comment: @user535733 the author already knows about the bug and they promised to fix it in the next minor release, but the bug is really annoying and I would like to fix it as soon as I can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no generic mechanism for renaming snaps nor editing yet. Seems you have to rename some `.jar` within the app. So you have to recreate the snap.

If this is the only solution of the bug, I suggest downloading Android Studio from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio) and installing manually.

Edit: If you need help regarding to installing Android Studio, feel free to reply.

Comment: There is a way to remount a snap read/write. There is a snap application called 'overlay' (you can install it from Snap Store) that does exactly this. Then, you need to write a script that is run `@reboot` in crontab that remounts the snap read/write using 'overlay' and renames the needed file(s).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to install Android Studio using [Ubuntu Make](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-make):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lyzardking/ubuntu-make
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-make

umake android android-studio
```

As the result it will be installed into `~/.local/share/umake/android/android-studio/` and you can edit any files here.

Answer (score 0):

*Maybe there is a way to downgrade to the previous version of Android Studio?*

Yes, this is very easy with snaps. Just run:

```
sudo snap revert android-studio
```

Explained in more detail [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198022/how-to-run-a-previous-version-of-a-snap-package).