# snap list doesn't match snap related loop mounts

Tags: 18.04, gnome, mount, snap, loop-device

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04. I'm not having any performance issues as indicated in [this related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1273170/more-snaps-than-on-snap-list) but I have far more snap loop mounts than snaps in the list.

```
me@me-Z370-HD3P:~$ df -h | grep snap
/dev/loop0      2.5M  2.5M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/826
/dev/loop1      162M  162M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/128
/dev/loop2      384K  384K     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/570
/dev/loop3      2.5M  2.5M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/748
/dev/loop4      2.3M  2.3M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/148
/dev/loop5      218M  218M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/60
/dev/loop6       98M   98M     0 100% /snap/core/10577
/dev/loop7      1.0M  1.0M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/93
/dev/loop10     163M  163M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145
/dev/loop9       65M   65M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1514
/dev/loop11     1.0M  1.0M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/100
/dev/loop13      56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1944
/dev/loop12      65M   65M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1513
/dev/loop14      98M   98M     0 100% /snap/core/10583
/dev/loop16      56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1932
/dev/loop15     2.3M  2.3M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/145
/dev/loop17     384K  384K     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/550
/dev/loop18     219M  219M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/66
me@me-Z370-HD3P:~$ snap list
Name                  Version                     Rev    Tracking         Publisher   Notes
core                  16-2.48.2                   10583  latest/stable    canonical✓  core
core18                20201210                    1944   latest/stable    canonical✓  base
gnome-3-28-1804       3.28.0-19-g98f9e67.98f9e67  145    latest/stable    canonical✓  -
gnome-3-34-1804       0+git.3556cb3               66     latest/stable    canonical✓  -
gnome-calculator      3.38.0+git7.c840c69c        826    latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
gnome-characters      v3.34.0+git9.eeab5f2        570    latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
gnome-logs            3.34.0                      100    latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
gnome-system-monitor  3.36.0-12-g35f88a56d7       148    latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
gtk-common-themes     0.1-50-gf7627e4             1514   latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
```

Why do I have 18 mounted snap loops when there are only 9 listed via `snap list` and are any of these redundant?

**Edit:**

Thanks to the comment from @mook765 here's the list of disabled snaps that one might assume are redundant.

```
snap list --all | grep disabled
core                  16-2.48                     10577  latest/stable    canonical*  core,disabled
core18                20200929                    1932   latest/stable    canonical*  base,disabled
gnome-3-28-1804       3.28.0-17-gde3d74c.de3d74c  128    latest/stable    canonical*  disabled
gnome-3-34-1804       0+git.3556cb3               60     latest/stable    canonical*  disabled
gnome-calculator      3.36.0+git9.96b95fd2        748    latest/stable/…  canonical*  disabled
gnome-characters      v3.34.0+git8.a46106b        550    latest/stable/…  canonical*  disabled
gnome-logs            3.34.0                      93     latest/stable/…  canonical*  disabled
gnome-system-monitor  3.36.0-12-g35f88a56d7       145    latest/stable/…  canonical*  disabled
gtk-common-themes     0.1-44-gb73fa2d             1513   latest/stable/…  canonical*  disabled
```

Comment: `snap list --all` will display all installed revisions.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this isn't really a problem to be solved as the number of versions to retain are [adjustable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1105878/snap-keeps-old-versions-of-programs-updates) and can't be less than 2 which is what I appear to have. This makes a certain amount of sense so that if you have trouble with the latest snap you can always [run a previous version.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198022/how-to-run-a-previous-version-of-a-snap-package)